# Calling service RegisterService removes "Success" property of response

Tags: servicestack

I am wrapping the Register service inside my own service like below snippet shows:

```cs
    var auth = request.ConvertTo<Register>();

    var regService = base.ResolveService<RegisterService>();

    RegisterResponse response = null;

    try
    {
        response = (RegisterResponse)regService.Post(auth);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error($"Unable to register user {request.Email}", ex);
        return new RegisterUserResponse
        {
            Success = false,
            PublicMessage = "Unable to register user",
            DebugMessage = ex.Message
        };
    }
```

When there is an error the `RegisterService` modifies the response and adds an empty `ResponseStatus` object and removes the `Success` property.

I don't mind the additional object getting added but is there anyway to stop it removing the `Success` property?

Comment: Please update your question to include the full raw HTTP Request & Response Headers as well as any non-default JsConfig configuration if you’re using any.

Comment: It was my JsConfig to blame.  I misunderstood one of the properties. Thanks for hint :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default ServiceStack does serialize bool properties, but the behavior you've described is if you've specifically configured it not to by setting:

```
JsConfig.Init(new Config {
    // ExcludeDefaultValues = true,
});
```

In which case all default values, like `false` for `bool` properties will not be emitted on the wire. If you want to keep this configuration and you want `false` to be serialized you have to change it so it's not the default value by making it nullable, e.g:

```
public class RegisterUserResponse
{
    public bool? Success { get; set; }
}
```